# Display Data In Table Using AJAX JSON PHP In Correct Way

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am making an admin panel. So I want to display data from database in table when page is load. I am Confused that, I display whole table from backend side in div or put data only ??

For Example :

```
success:function(response){
    $("#result").html(result);
}
```

That Will Display Whole Table In result div. That will Come From Backend side.

**OR**

```
 success:function(response){
        $("#result").html('<table><tr><td>'+response.name+'</td><td>'+response.password+'</td></tr>');
    }
```

If This is The Way for printing data in table then It will Print Only the row at once. Not full data in each .

Please Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: It is good to show data in paging wise table. It depend what you want to show your user , some time all data is not much relevant to user, so it good to show a partial of all records

Comment: So... where to display an id from json for editing purpose of form. It is bydefault or set id in hidden field

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya Do you wanna accept any of the following answers?

Answer (score 3):

It would be obviously better to get the data from the backend as a JSON output and use the JSON from the response to construct the table in the client side. The main reasons being:

1. Lesser code footprint between the client and server.
2. Ability to change the view, if JSON, it is not tied with HTML.

In future, if you want to change the structure or if you need to use the same output in a different page, in a different way, you don't need to change the underlying PHP, instead, you can just change the rendering mechanism.

Have the server sent out a JSON output like this:

```
[{
  "name": "Praveen",
  "age": 27
}, {
  "name": "Kumar",
  "age": 25
}]
```

And make the JavaScript do the rest.

```js
var jsonResponse = [{
  "name": "Praveen",
  "age": 27
}, {
  "name": "Kumar",
  "age": 25
}];
$('body').append(function () {
  var table = $('<table />');
  var headr = $('<tr />');
  headr.append('<th>Name</th>');
  headr.append('<th>Age</th>');
  headr.appendTo(table);
  $.each(jsonResponse, function (i, v) {
    var tr = $('<tr />');
    tr.append('<td>' + v.name + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + v.age + '</td>');
    tr.appendTo(table);
  });
  return table;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think. It is time consuming.. At Backend side, i will use while loop for create json array and at front side i will use foreach loop for set json variable. So it is better to use direct table from backend in Response ??

Comment: @SachinSanchaniya Giving out a table is not a good idea IMO. But yeah, if you feel that's better, you can go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Your both options correct but I found it is good practice separating logic and views, means it is good to generate html view in front-end.

Now, to generate table view with multiple rows, your response data should be properly structured for example json object array.

If you got my explanation then you can follow this post:
[Loop through a JSON array to create a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434012/loop-through-a-json-array-to-create-a-table)

Let me know for any queries

Comment: LoL. Wow. That was quick! :D

Comment: Ok. but after getting response in ajax as shown in my second example than it will affect the pagination and searching when i create the code of pagination ??

Comment: In your second example you hard coded only one row. Follow the example as Praveen provided and the link I given. Now If the scenario is you have 100 rows for example and you want to show 10 rows at a time. Then you also need to keep track of your page number. You can paste your code so that I can write sample code for you as your needs. I would also like to recommend Datatable JS library for you to check.

Comment: I think. It is time consuming.. At Backend side, i will use while loop for create json array and at front side i will use foreach loop for set json variable. So it is better to use direct table from backend in Response ??

Comment: In terms of time both solution time consuming. In server side or client side you need time to process loop. As per my knowledge and practice separating business logic from presentation is a popular fashion. Again if we think about time, you know a PHP requests handled in a queue in server thus is it not better to reduce the load of server and make it free asap?