# Formatting JSON.stringify output as table

Tags: json

I have below codes:

```
<pre id="eventoutput">Result Output: ...</pre>      
<script>  // Show Output
 (function (L, document) {


  map.on('measurefinish', function (evt) {
      writeResults(evt);
    });

    function writeResults (results) {
      document.getElementById('eventoutput').innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
        Points: results.points
      }, null, 2);
    }
  })(window.L, window.document);
</script>
```

And its output is shown as

```
{
  "Points": [
    {
      "lat": 11.570852645045665,
      "lng": 104.79034423828126
    },
    {
      "lat": 11.61121119698555,
      "lng": 104.85076904296876
    },
    {
      "lat": 11.566816469367417,
      "lng": 104.88235473632814
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to format it as a table with Column name Points, Lat, Lng and Row representing each data.

Could you please help me how I can accomplish this.

Comment: since you have the array, you just need to iterate, and for each element create a table row.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the array and render the table.

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21434012/loop-through-a-json-array-to-create-a-table)